# Linear Regression issues

Tags: python, scikit-learn, statistics, linear-regression

I'm trying to run a linear regression for 2 columns of data (IMF_VALUES, BBG_FV)

I have this code:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import linear_model
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
raw_data = pd.read_csv("IMF and BBG Fair Values.csv")
ISO_TH = raw_data[["IMF_VALUE","BBG_FV"]]


filtered_TH = ISO_TH[np.isfinite(raw_data['BBG_FV'])]

npMatrix = np.matrix(filtered_TH) 
IMF_VALUE, BBG_FV = npMatrix[:,0], npMatrix[:,1]


regression = linear_model.LinearRegression
regression.fit(IMF_VALUE, BBG_FV)
```

When I run this as a test, I get this error and I really have no idea why:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-1ee2fa0bbed1> in <module>()
      1 regression = linear_model.LinearRegression
----> 2 regression.fit(IMF_VALUE, BBG_FV)

TypeError: fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
```

Comment: Checkout the shapes of `IMF_VALUE` and `BBG_FV` values. The `BBG_FV` may not be array.

Comment: You forgot to initialize the regression object. You need to do: `regression = linear_model.LinearRegression()`. Observe the brackets at the end. Without them, `regression` is a class, not initialized object model.

Answer (score -2):

Make sure that both are one dimensional arrays:

```python
regression.fit(np.array(IMF_VALUE).reshape(-1,1), np.array(BBG_FV).reshape(-1,1))
```

Comment: Hey - thank you both so much. The errors went away! Im  going to keep trying!